# Can I do Gaussian elimination with a rectangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm writing some linear algebra scripts to understand the stuff I'm reading. I was wondering if I can only use square matrices as input for Gaussian Elimination, my guess is yes because permutation matrices can only be square but I wan't to be sure.

Comment: Yes, You Can! :) But instead of ending up with a triangular matrix, you will have a **echelon form**. :)

Comment: @H.R. How do I do permutation then? to my understanding you can permute rows and columns because you multiply them by a permutation matrix, but the permutation matrix is always square

Comment: I think you can still make permutation matrices for interchanging rows or columns.

Comment: @H.R.: Care to answer the question with a link to an algorithm or the theory?

Comment: @jvriesem: Hi. :) I just provided a comment. Please write an answer with adequate details if you have the time. :)